# When is catch() called when using docRef.get() in FireStore?

Tags: angular, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

In Angular 5 with FireStore and angularfire2, when retrieving the contents of a single document using `docRef.get()`, what scenario would cause the `catch` statement to be executed? How can I produce such an error?

[image]

If I interpret the note below the code correctly, it means that if there is *no document*, it will return `null`, rather than throwing an error.

**So my question is, in what case would it actually throw an error and go into the catch statement?**

Comment: one i believe `permission-denied`: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.