# Handling errors when getting firebase document

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120326/error-handling-when-getting-document-from-firestore), I have the following function to get document from a firebase collection:

```
function getCustomerForReal(customerId): Promise<Customer> {
return Promise.resolve() // neutral starter promise 
.then(() => {
    var customerDocument = fb.customersCollection.doc(customerId).withConverter(customerConverter);
    if(customerDocument) {
        return customerDocument.get()
    } else {
        throw new Error("Error"); 
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    throw new Error('Error: Getting document:');
})
.then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        var data = doc.data() as Customer;
        return data;
    } else {
        throw new Error('No such document!');
    }
});
};
```

And this function is being called like so:

```
customerRouter.get('/get/:customerId/', express.json(), async function (req, res) {
customerApi.getCustomerForReal(req.params.customerId)
.then(customer => {
    console.log(customer)
    res.status(200)
    res.json(customer)
    res.end();
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(400).send(error)
})
});
```

But when I send a request in which the document doesn't exist, the error gets thrown,  but isn't getting caught but the catch in the second function.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The “no such document” error gets thrown, but isn’t caught by the router.